# RebindOperation doesn't changing bindings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that my game contain rebind settings. So here, my code that should rebind `InputAction`:

```
public void ChangeShortcut(InputAction action, int bindingIndex)
{
    rebindOperation?.Cancel();
    action.Disable();
    rebindOperation = action.PerformInteractiveRebinding(bindingIndex);
    rebindOperation.OnCancel(operation => CleanUp(action));
    rebindOperation.OnComplete(operation => CleanUp(action));
    rebindOperation.Start();
}

private void CleanUp(InputAction action)
{
    action.Enable();
    rebindOperation?.Dispose();
    rebindOperation = null;
}
```

I have tested it, `OnComplete` calling, but binding path not changing.

P.S.

```
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "name": "Player",
            "id": "e90ea4bb-b669-4ed0-a745-9af32f078bb8",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Jump",
                    "type": "Button",
                    "id": "08632208-dbf2-4c6c-8ac8-d065fca7164e",
                    "expectedControlType": "Button",
                    "processors": "",
                    "interactions": ""
                },
                {
                    "name": "Shoot",
                    "type": "Button",
                    "id": "c8ba45a6-9e54-46e6-917e-fcf93fa63400",
                    "expectedControlType": "Button",
                    "processors": "",
                    "interactions": ""
                }
            ],
            "bindings": [
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": "c791a748-e08c-496d-9348-4f075a7b6eb1",
                    "path": "<Keyboard>/space",
                    "interactions": "",
                    "processors": "",
                    "groups": "Computer",
                    "action": "Jump",
                    "isComposite": false,
                    "isPartOfComposite": false
                },
                {
                    "name": "",
                    "id": "8e1a4a5c-a3d3-4b75-b742-976c0190832f",
                    "path": "<Mouse>/leftButton",
                    "interactions": "",
                    "processors": "",
                    "groups": "Computer",
                    "action": "Shoot",
                    "isComposite": false,
                    "isPartOfComposite": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're complete and failed actions points the same method, how can you be sure it's succesfull?

Comment: @oistikbal I sure, because I tested it with Debug.Log, and print "Complete" if complete, and "Cancel" if cancel.

Comment: Try to print your actionmap overloadings as json.

Comment: @oistikbal I add it to my question

Comment: This is not your whole map right? İf so you maybe rebind succesfull but use different action map.

Comment: @oistikbal This is whole map, and I have only one map - "Player"

Comment: You should print overloads not the actual map. İf the overloaded one is empty that means theres no rebind.

Comment: @oistikbal How can I get overloading map? Is it mean I should print rebindOperation.action.actionMap?

Comment: P.S. if I print rebindOperation.action.actionMap as json after complete, but before dispose, it not empty, and it has same content like actualMap. (keys not rebinded in it)

Comment: ```actionmap.asset.SaveBindingOverridesAsJson()```` this wil give you a string, print it. it shouldn't be null or empty if it succefully binded if it is and your and your action not moving, you maybe using different actionmap and bind another actionmap.

Comment: @oistikbal Unfortunately, I haven't this method in a ```actionMap.asset```

Comment: that's a extenion method inside ``UnityEngine.InputSystem`` namespace.

Comment: @oistikbal I have ```using UnityEngine.InputSystem```.

Comment: @oistikbal I update my unity version, and print action.bindings[bindingIndex].overridePath, and it changing.

Comment: @oistikbal Thank you for you help! "Override" word got me thinking about right way to close my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all, who will run into this problem.

`action.bindings[bindingIndex].path` - is constant, it not changing, even you rebinded your action.
Actual binding is `action.bindings[bindingIndex].overridePath`. If you have override binding, usual path will not work, but override work. With this, you can reset you bindings, because `action.bindings[bindingIndex].path` leave constant all time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your binding operation

```
rebindOperation.OnApplyBinding((op, keyPath) =>
{
    action.ApplyBindingOverride(0, keyPath);
});
```